# Running JUnit 4 from command line on Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4

I currently have ClasspathSuite set up to run all of my JUnit tests. I'm working on trying to get the ClasspathSuite class to run from the command line. When I am in the bin directory and run this command:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MySuite.class
```

I get:

```
JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: MySuite.class

Time: 0.002

OK (0 tests)
```

I also tried running the same command with the absolute path to the file, resulting in the same error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take off the `.class` part.  Java knows to look in that file when you specify the class name.

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MySuite
```

Comment: Thought that would do it, unfortunately got the same thing: Could not find class: MySuite.

Comment: Can you post the top of the MySuite class?  Just the package and class information?

Comment: Actually just got it. Had to add a few extra things to the classpath. Now it's going strong. Thanks though.