# Running JUnit test on the command line in Linux environment

Tags: java, junit, command-line

I have been trying to run following command on the command line:

```
java -cp junit-4.13-beta-2.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:./src org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.whatever.path
```

But I get following error:

```
JUnit version 4.13-beta-2
.E
Time: 0.002
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [com.whatever.path]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.whatever.path
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:27)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:98)
    ... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

com.whatever.path is the package+class name, and this test runs successfully through eclipse. 
All the java and class files are located under src/com/whatever/path, and they are all compiled.
I have set the classpath, and also tried to run it with mvn command, too.(which resulted in "NO TESTS WERE EXECUTED" error.)

Please let me know what is going on! :(
(Also let me know if this is a duplicate. I have been trying to try millions of different ways to run this test on my command line, but it seems like none of the cases online helped.)

Comment: Please try setting up classpath info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: I ran this command before, but it didn't help :( set CLASSPATH=~/path/to/junit-4.13-beta-2.jar:~/path/to/src/

Comment: May be you need to close console window for it to take effect..

Comment: @bestinamir just did, no luck..

Comment: Not sure but may be build automation tools like Maven and Gradle would help..

Comment: @bestinamir tried maven, but also got NO TESTS WERE EXECUTED error..

Comment: Similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17846513/10634638

Comment: @JULS _src/com/whatever/path, and they are all compiled._ Yes, but are they really compiled into `src`? In Eclipse compiled class files are usually placed into `bin` although you can define any output folder in project properties.

Comment: @Würgspaß yes I set my default output folder to be ~/blahblah/src, and I am running my command in ~/blahblah

Comment: @bestinamir maybe I need to add more things on my classpath... hmh

Comment: I would suggest to add all compiled test files to a jar and specify the jar file in your `-cp` argument.